# mat-select-country - unable to set initial value

Tags: angular, material-design

I am using the mat-select-country to display and select from a list of countries.

```
      <mat-select-country  appearance="outline" country="IN" [itemsLoadSize]="5"
      (onCountrySelected)="onCountrySelected($event)">
  </mat-select-country>
```

When I set **country="IN"**, it displays only the flag but not the name of the country.
**Only on click of the input box will it show the country.** I am trying to default the value for my country field when my page loads.

The link for the above control
[angular-material-extensions/select-country](https://laptrinhx.com/angular-material-component-that-allow-users-to-select-a-country-or-nationality-with-an-autocomplete-feature-3265035597/)

I have also tried using the value, no luck. Any  help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the data from an Http request?

Comment: No, I am using the one that the control comes with.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question - what if I am getting only the alpha2Code from my API and not the other fields like name, numericCode, etc.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

This issue was resolved with a new release: https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/select-country/issues/46

Documentation: https://angular-material-extensions.github.io/select-country/doc/index.html

Comment: Thank you. I have a question, what if I am getting only the alpha2Code from my API and not the other fields like name, numericCode etc. Can i pass empty and would it still work?

Comment: Also, this is what the documentation says. It does not work with the object. It has to be a string.

country Input() string - Value to be set to the input (possible values are Country interface properties, case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

1. Import the module

   import {Country} from '@angular-material-extensions/select-country';
2. Make variable

   ```
    defaultCountry: Country = {
    name: 'Indonesia',
    alpha2Code: 'ID',
    alpha3Code: 'IND',
    numericCode: '276'
   ```

   };
3. Make a function

   onCountrySelected(country: Country) {
   console.log(country);
   }
4. Call in view like this

   <mat-select-country label="Country" [value]="defaultCountry" appearance="outline" (onCountrySelected)="onCountrySelected($event)">

Comment: As ugly as this sounds, this seems to be the only working solution...